# Is Angular2 ViewMetadata deprecated?

Tags: angular

Angular2: ViewMetadata (a.k.a. `@View`)

Doc: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/ViewMetadata-class.html

Code: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.0.0-alpha.45/modules/angular2/src/core/metadata/view.ts#L32-L143

Documentation for `ViewMetadata` is replaced to `ComponentMetadata` but declaration still exists. 
It'll be removed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Angular2 [changelog](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md):

> 2.0.0-alpha.40
>
> core: add syntax sugar to make @View optional (bd31b01)

This is now optional and `template`, `directives` etc  be put inside of @Component.

Although logically this is very nice separation (component & view) and I would keep it.

Comment: but as of angular beta 10 @view has been deprecated.